# WINE starting an application

Tags: terminal, mac, permission, wine

[image: The window that opens]I built WINE from source, following their INSTALL.UNIX file, so I start wine via Terminal, a UI appears:

> Microsoft Windows 6.1.7601
>
> Z: \Users\USER\Downloads\wine-4.20>

so I write

> start "\Users\USER\Downloads\PROGRAM.exe"

it gives the output

> File not found.

so I suspect it may be a permission thing, I go to "Security & Privacy" settings and give permission to everything I can in the wine-4.20 folder.

**I can't fix it**

Am I doing something wrong?

EDIT:
Well my own answer fixed it, except apparently I need to install Wine Mono

Comment: The command in the screenshot doesn‘t mach the command on the text. Also: where exactly is the application you want to run?

Comment: I know it doesn't match, well, actually when I was running it, it matched but the File not found blocked the text. I tried running the command several times with and without quotes. Also, I don't have a plan for where it will run. But I think I know the way

/d directory   Start the program in the specified directory.

Comment: Actually there are more options I know, I learned them when I did 

./wine start /Users/kerem/Downloads/pivotAnimator_v4-2.exe  

in the normal terminal my Mac's terminal. Actually there's a strong thing it should be run like that, but it gives the error

001b:err:start:wmain Unknown option 'L"/Users/kerem/Downloads/pivotAnimator_v4-2.exe"'

Comment: There is a ./wine start command, but am I messing the directory up? It should be the exact directory. Maybe I should cd to the directory and then do ./wine start.
Edit:
Oh, you can't cd to a file, only directory!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write /unix as a flag, as you are one a Mac. You can specify the directory Mac-style that way and it will work, just don't forget the quotes.

Maybe these will help you:

> Start a program, or open a document in the program normally used for
> files with that suffix. Usage: start [options] program_filename [...]
> start [options] document_filename
>
> Options: "title"        Specifies the title of the child windows. /d
> directory   Start the program in the specified directory. /b
> Don't create a new console for the program. /i             Start the
> program with fresh environment variables. /min           Start the
> program minimized. /max           Start the program maximized. /low
> Start the program in the idle priority class. /normal        Start the
> program in the normal priority class. /high          Start the program
> in the high priority class. /realtime      Start the program in the
> realtime priority class. /abovenormal   Start the program in the
> abovenormal priority class. /belownormal   Start the program in the
> belownormal priority class. /node n        Start the program on the
> specified NUMA node. /affinity mask Start the program with the
> specified affinity mask. /wait          Wait for the started program
> to finish, then exit with its
> exit code. /unix          Use a Unix filename and start the file like Windows
> explorer. /ProgIDOpen    Open a document using the specified progID. /?             Display this help and exit.

Still, there is a error, but at least this fixes one for me:
0023:err:mscoree:CLRRuntimeInfo_GetRuntimeHost Wine Mono is not installed